# idle_container configuration in openwhisk

Tags: openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

Currently, the Invoker component configuration in the *application.conf* has the following configuration for container proxy :

```
  container-proxy {
    timeouts {
      # The "unusedTimeout" in the ContainerProxy,
      #aka 'How long should a container sit idle until we kill it?'
      idle-container = 10 minutes
      pause-grace = 50 milliseconds
  }
```

I installed *openwhisk* on *kubernetes* via *Helm*.

How can I configure the idle-container in the *values.yaml* or *cluster.yaml*?
I tried the following method in *values.yaml* and *cluster.yaml* but does not work:

```
whisk:
  containerProxy:
    timeouts:
      idleContainer: "3minutes"
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say does not work?

Comment: @YLR I mean, the idle time of the containers remains the same as 10 minutes and does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override default values from a `.conf` file, you set environment variables that start with CONFIG_ in the invoker/controller pods.  Concretely to change `whisk.container-proxy.timeouts.idle-container` you would define the environment variable `CONFIG_whisk_containerProxy_timeouts_idleContainer` to have the desired value.

In the current OpenWhisk helm chart, this requires editing the yaml files for `invoker-pod.yaml` or `container-pod.yaml` to add the additional  environment variable definition.  There are multiple `CONFIG_` variables being defined in these files, so you should have examples to follow.

Comment: I edited invoker-pod.yaml as follows:                               -name:"CONFIG_whisk_containerProxy_timeouts_idleContainer"
value{{.Values.whisk.containerProxy.timeouts.idleContainer }}                                                                                   and values.yaml as mentioned in question                                           but still the idle-container value is 10 minutes